# Get dependency map API [pact-broker]

Tags: testing, pact, pact-broker

Is there a way to get full dependency map of all contracts from the Pact Broker (preferably in json format)?

There is an API call used in the graph: `https://<broker-url>/groups/<service>.csv` to get data to draw the graph, but that is not great for parsing and requires a call to find all services and then a call for each service to get the dependencies.

It would be nice to have one call with a full dependency map in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! There is a HAL browser built in to broker, which enables you to follow the graph programmatically.

For example, you could run a query like this and filter with `jq` on the subset of properties you need, and re-order the output:

```
curl -v -u 'dXfltyFMgNOFZAxr8io9wJ37iUpY42M:O5AIZWxelWbLvqMd8PkAVycBJh2Psyg1' https://test.pact.dius.com.au/pacts/latest | jq '.pacts[]._embedded | select(.consumer.name | contains("AWSSummiteer")) | .consumer.name + "->" + .provider.name'
```

Which produces something like:

```
"AWSSummiteerSentimentSNSProvider->AWSSummiteerTwitterSNSProvider"
"AWSSummiteerTwitterSNSConsumer->AWSSummiteerTwitterSNSProvider"
"AWSSummiteerTwitterSNSProvider->Twitter"
"AWSSummiteerWeb->AWSSummiteerIoT"
"AWSSummiteerWeb->AWSSummiteerIoTPresignedUrl"
"AWSSummiteerWeb->AWSSummiteerSentimentSNSProvider"
"AWSSummiteerWeb->AWSSummiteerTwitterSNSConsumer"
"AWSSummiteerWeb->AWSSummiteerWeb"
```

which you could pipe into [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to create pretty charts but of course you could translate this into any format you like.

Here is the full graphviz visualisation:

```
echo "digraph { ranksep=3; ratio=auto; overlap=false; node [  shape = plaintext, fontname = "Helvetica" ];" > latest.dot ; curl -v -u 'dXfltyFMgNOFZAxr8io9wJ37iUpY42M:O5AIZWxelWbLvqMd8PkAVycBJh2Psyg1' https://test.pact.dius.com.au/pacts/latest | jq '.pacts[]._embedded | select(.consumer.name | contains("AWSSummiteer")) | .consumer.name + "->" + .provider.name' | tr -d '"' |  sed 's/-/_/g' | sed 's/_>/->/g' >> latest.dot; echo "}" >> latest.dot
dot latest.dot -otest.png -Tpng
```

which creates this pretty picture:

[image: Dummy architecture]